# Redirect based on previous url path Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to redirect a user to one of four different pages based how they got to the landing page, however as I'm so new to this, I can't figure out how to make it work in javascript.

In la mans terms, I'm trying to do something like this ->

IF user was on PAGE-1 before this page, then User automatically gets redirected to PAGE-2,

IF user comes from PAGE-A, they automatically get redirected to PAGE-B.

Can anyone help me figure this out?? Thanks in advance and apologies if it's a super basic question!

Here's the script I've been using so far, problem is it seems to redirect to the first page regardless of where the source is...

```
if (document.referrer !== "http://www.wearethedreammakers.com/pages/free-signup") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.example.com?test1";
}

else if (document.referrer !== "http://www.wearethedreammakers.com/pages/free-signup-2") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com?test2";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have script that sets last page inside a cookie or inside localStorage instead of using document.referrer. Something like:

On first page:

```
localStorage.setItem('page', 'page_1');
```

On redirect page:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('page') === 'page_1') {
 window.location = '/page';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!!

I'm trying to implement it, but my ignorance is holding me back again...

Is it a function to insert local storage, e.g like this?

<script type="text/javascript">
function {
localStorage.setItem('page', 'page_1');}

</script>

Is there a way to test that has been done correctly?

can it be a full url in the window.location = '/page'; section? 

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I've now got that bit working, which is great! Thank you!

I'm now going to attempt this with the different variations (e.g. the 'else if' statement) however, once I've got it set up, I've have all of the different pages stored in my local storage, is there an easy way for me to clear that so I can test it's working?